# How do I handle a custom scheme from a Fragement in Android?

Tags: android

I'm working with an Android app which I inherited. On a certain screen, which is defined as a Fragment, I need to open an external web page, and then wait for that web page to do a redirect back to my app using a custom scheme.

I understand how to open the web page, and I understand how to set up an intent-filter in my Manifest that responds to the custom scheme by starting another activity. But, starting another activity is not what I need. Instead, I need for control to return to the Fragment that originally started this process.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: I guess you are attaching the scheme filter to the main activity. How about creating a new activity with no UI and make it receives all scheme intents. From here, after receiving the URL and doing some data extraction, we can delegate the coming uri into the other place via pub-sub pattern (eventBus, livedata, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I just got this working today after spending some time on this. You can do this via Fragments easily.

What you need to use is a WebView inside a fragment and control the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method.

I have also seen this method not always being used the right way, no one plays with the `webResourceRequest` it returns.

So , lets say we have our fragment layout having a webview inside it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ui.auth.LoginFragment">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/fragmentWebView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

   </FrameLayout>
```

So we have our webview defined in a fragment now. Lets say you have a cusom URI scheme that you want to handle here.

This is what you need to do in your fragment,handle the response accordingly, I am calling a function which based on a response opens other fragment using `fragment transaction`.

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val loginView  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false)
        val webView: WebView = loginView.findViewById(R.id.fragmentWebView)
        val webSetting = webView.settings
        webSetting.builtInZoomControls = true
        webSetting.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.loadUrl(url!!)
        webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {

            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, webResourceRequest: WebResourceRequest?): Boolean {
                return if(webResourceRequest?.url?.scheme.equals("myscheme")){
                    fetchAndConfigureUserIdentity(webResourceRequest?.url.toString(),loginView)
                    true
                }else{
                    false
                }
            }
        }
        return loginView
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the intent in the activity and use the fragment manager to populate late the fragment you wish. Replace Action and Fragment with your own.

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(final Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    parseIntent(intent);
}

private void parseIntent(Intent intent) {
    final String action = intent.getAction();

    if (action != null) {
        if (Action.<ONE>.equals(action)) {
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            Fragment<ONE> fragment = (Fragment<ONE>) Fragment.instantiate(this,
            Fragment<ONE>.class.getCanonicalName(),
            getIntent().getExtras());
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.fragment_id, fragment);
            ft.commit();
        } else if (Action.<TWO>.equals(action)) {
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            Fragment<TWO> fragment = (Fragment<TWO>) Fragment.instantiate(this,
            Fragment<TWO>.class.getCanonicalName(),
            getIntent().getExtras());
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.fragment_id, fragment);
            ft.commit();
        } 
    }
}
```